# Scipy Detrend in python

Tags: python, scipy, forecasting

I detrended my data in python using the following code from **scipy.signal.detrend**

```
detrended =signal.detrend(feature, axis=-1, type='constant', bp=0, overwrite_data=True)
np.savetxt('constant detrend.csv', detrended, delimiter=',', fmt='%s')
```

The last line saves the data into a csv file then i reload this data to run some models. I found that the my RandomForest model performs really well with the detrended dataset.

So next will be to make forecasts using this model. However i am a bit unsure of how i can move from the detrended dataset to a more meaningful dataset that i can understand. From my understanding the detrend removed the mean and normalized the data. But if i do my predictions i need to be able to see the actual numbers of my forecasts not the detrended numbers.

Is there a way i can readd the mean and renormalize to get a 'meanful dataset' that i can interpret. For example my dataset has a rainfall variable. So for each month i can see how much it rained. But when i detrended, the rainfall value is no longer the actual rainfall value. When i make forecasts i want to be able to say in this month it rained 200mm but my forecasts don't tell me this since the data has been detrended.

Any help would be appraciated.

Comment: Can you share what you imagine the data you will be "retrending" will look like? I'm mostly concerned with a sample of the shapes of the input data and the predictions you will make.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the docs, [`detrend`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.detrend.html) simply removes the least squares line fit from the data. When you use `type='constant'`, it's even simpler, since it just removes the mean:

> If `type == 'constant'`, only the mean of *data* is subtracted.

The source code bears this out. After checking the inputs, the entire computation is done in one line ([`scipy/signal/signaltools.py`, line 3261](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/adc4f4f7bab120ccfab9383aba272954a0a12fb0/scipy/signal/signaltools.py#L3261)):

> ```
>  ret = data - np.expand_dims(np.mean(data, axis), axis)
> ```

The easiest way to get the subtracted mean is to implement the calculation by hand, given how simple it is.

```
mean = np.mean(feature, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
detrended = feature - mean
```

You can save the mean to a file, or do whatever else you want with it. To "retrend", just add the mean back:

```
point = prediction + mean
```

If you had some other manipulation you were concerned with, like normalizing to the maximum, you could handle it the same way.

```
max = np.amax(detrended, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
detrended /= max
```

In this case you'd have to multiply before offsetting to retrend:

```
point = prediction * max + mean
```

Simple manipulations like this are easy to reproduce by hand. A more complicated function might be hard to reproduce reliably, but would also be more likely to return the parameters it uses, at least optionally.

Comment: Thanks for this @Mad Physicist. But the line `mean = np.mean(feature, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
detrended = feature - mean` is removing the mean by row not column. Each column is a different feature so i need it to remove the mean based on the mean of the column not row

Comment: does it make a difference wether i take row mean or column mean?

Comment: @Tamarie You should use `axis=<whatever you need>` in all cases. If you column means, set `axis=0`. `-1` just takes the last axis, which leaves rows. See an example here: https://ideone.com/XOEVpe

Comment: @Tamarie. That depends on what you are doing. Your current example is showing `axis=-1`. Your comment says you want `axis=0`. It's very much up to you what you want to do. Of course it will make a difference how you do it, but only you know what your data means in the end.

Comment: @Tamarie. I'm glad it worked out for you. Data analysis can be a real PITA